# How to extract hashtags from a string in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, parsing

```
Declare @text='i #want to extract all #hastag out of this string, #delhi #Traffic'
```

Desired output would be in string:  `"#want,#hastag,#delhi,#Traffic"` or table.

Comment: Use `charindex` and `substring`. Search for the first `#` character in string, get its position with `charindex`. Then get position of first space character starting from this position and get part of string between these positions. Repeat until the end of string.

Comment: SQL Server isn't really the best tool for this.  Do you have access to .NET or Java?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes i have access to .net.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try it like this

```
Declare @text VARCHAR(100)='i #want to extract all #hastag out of this string, #delhi #Traffic';

WITH Casted(ToXml) AS (SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT @text AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),' ','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML))
SELECT SUBSTRING(x.value('.','nvarchar(max)'),2,1000)
FROM Casted
CROSS APPLY ToXml.nodes('x[substring((./text())[1],1,1)="#"]') AS A(x)
```

The result (I've cut away the `#`, just take away the outer `SUBSTRING` if you need it)

```
want
hastag
delhi
Traffic
```

Or as the string you placed as expected output:

Try it like this

```
Declare @text VARCHAR(100)='i #want to extract all #hastag out of this string, #delhi #Traffic';

WITH Casted(ToXml) AS (SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT @text AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),' ','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML))
SELECT STUFF(
(
SELECT ','+x.value('.','nvarchar(max)')
FROM Casted
CROSS APPLY ToXml.nodes('x[substring((./text())[1],1,1)="#"]') AS A(x)
FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')
```

The result

```
#want,#hastag,#delhi,#Traffic
```

Comment: Nice one! +1 from my side!

Comment: FYI: if your requirement includes hashtags that aren't delim'd by spaces, this won't work as is.  It does work great on the sample though.  Mine has punctuation and html that has to be cleaned off first for this to work.

Comment: @archangel76 If you cut bread and the result is not convincing because you are using a chain saw - you should not blame the tool. T-SQL is not known for procedural string parsing... Such an issue should better be solved with a *real* programming language. But OP asks for `in T-SQL` explicitly...

Comment: @Shnugo I was happy for your code, which I used with only slight modifications. I was only sharing so that others who may have similar but slightly different requirements don't accidentally get bit by the results, as it's not directly clear the use case scenarios that this would and would not work for. I know tsql isn't great for this task. And I wasn't knocking your solution (I upvoted it). My aim was to help others with a clarification. Cheers!

Comment: @archangel76 sorry, I got this wrong... Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly code of split function for SQL server, you can find it anywhere on the net. Basically, I would use split function first, to split whole sentence by words, then just select those which got '#' char with them

```
declare @String nvarchar(200) = 'i #want to extract all #hastag
                 out of this string, #delhi #Traffic'
DECLARE @Delimiter char(1) = ' '

if object_id('tempdb..#slicedWords') is not null drop table #slicedWords
create table #slicedWords (word nvarchar(100))

declare @idx int
declare @slice varchar(8000)

select @idx = 1
if len(@String)<1 or @String is null return

while @idx!= 0
begin
set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)
    if @idx!=0
        set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)
    else
        set @slice = @String

    if(len(@slice)>0)
        insert
        into #slicedWords(word) values(@slice)

    set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)

    if len(@String) = 0 
        break
end

select * from #slicedWords where word like '%#%'
```

Or if you want in single string, change last select with

```
select  STUFF((SELECT ', ' + word 
                from #slicedWords where word like '%#%'
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
```

Comment: If you search for split functions you will find a lot of better approaches than a `WHILE` loop.

Comment: That is correct, I just grabbed first one google gave me, but anyway i would go with @Shnugo 's solution now anyway, as I wasn't aware of that possibility and it seems a lot cleaner then split function

Answer (score 0):

Solution using XML:

```
DECLARE @text nvarchar(max)='i #want to extract all #hastag out of this string, #delhi #Traffic'

SELECT STUFF( -- is used to separate all hashtags with commas
    (
        SELECT ',' + t.c.value('.','nvarchar(max)')
        FROM (
            --In this part we convert input text into XML
            SELECT CAST('<a>'+REPLACE((SELECT @text as [*] FOR XML PATH('')),' ','</a><a>')+'</a>' as xml) as x
            ) as x
        CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/a') as t(c) 
        WHERE t.c.exist('. [contains(., "#")]') = 1 --check if each part contains #
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,'')
```

Output:

```
#want,#hastag,#delhi,#Traffic
```

Comment: If there is a `#` somewhere else, this would be returned too. And this would break, if the string contains forbidden characters such as `<, >, &` and many special characters which need escaping...

Comment: @Shnugo _If there is a # somewhere else, this would be returned too._ - same applies to your solutions :) _And this would break..._ - yeah, this one can be overrun with `SELECT @text as [*] FOR XML PATH('')` in `REPLACE` part.

Comment: *same applies to your solution* No, the predicate `'x[substring((./text())[1],1,1)="#"]'` will filter only those which have the `#` as the first character. Well, it would include a *naked #*, which could easily be solved with a len-check. You are right with your second point, but in this case one **must** use `...,TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(max)')` to re-code all entities...

Answer (score 0):

One more approach using [Numbers](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable) table

```
Declare @text varchar(max)='i #want to extract all #hastag out of this string, #delhi #Traffic'


select  
substring(@text,number+1, 
case when (charindex(' ',@text,number+1)-number+1)<=0 then 100 else charindex(' ',@text,number+1)-number end )
from
numbers
where number<len(@text) and substring(@text,number,1)=' '
and substring(@text,number+1,1)='#'
```

**Output:**

```
#want 
#hastag 
#delhi 
#Traffic
```

Comment: Hi, I corrected a not needed comma and btw: If you place `WITH numbers(number) AS SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM master..spt_values)` before the select, you would not even need a physical number's table

Comment: @Shnugo:thank you for correction,i had a numbers table so used it

Answer (score 0):

You could try this more simple way:

```
select * 
from string_split('Hola adios #Hashtag Hello Good #Morning', ' ')
where value like '#%'
```