# SQL Server : extract hashtags from column of text

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I understand that this answer here: [How to extract hashtags from a string in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42201150/how-to-extract-hashtags-from-a-string-in-t-sql)
explains how to extract hashtags from a declared string variable, but how do I apply this operation to an entire column of strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a CROSS APPLY.  **Just for fun**, remove the final WHERE, and see what happens

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,SomeText varchar(max))
Insert into @YourTable values
 (1, '#want to extract all #hastag out of this string, #delhi #Traffic')
,(2, '#bunny #hastag #donetodeath')

Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                      ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(replace(A.SomeText,char(13),' '),' ','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
             ) B
 Where B.RetVal like '#%'
```

**Returns**

```
ID  RetSeq  RetVal
1   1       #want
1   5       #hastag
1   10      #delhi
1   11      #Traffic
2   1       #bunny
2   2       #hastag
2   3       #donetodeath
```

Comment: Thank you! This was extremely helpful, however I found that it doesn't pick up hashtags when the string has new lines in it. For example if there are hashtags after the new line in a string, those are not returned and as I'm not familiar with the method of string manipulation in SQL, I don't know how to accomplish that

Comment: @teku45 Take a peek at the UDF here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42958278/sql-server-search-using-like-while-ignoring-blank-spaces/42958939#42958939  or you can just add  ...  replace(A.SomeText,char(13),' ')